# How to ensure consistency of enums in Java serialization?

Tags: java, serialization, enums

When I serialize an object, I can use the serialVersionUID mechanism at the class level to ensure the compatibility of the two types.

However, what happens when I serialize fields of enum values? Is there a way to ensure that the enum type has not been manipulated between serialization and deserialization?

Suppose that I have an enum like OperationResult {SUCCESS, FAIL}, and a field called "result" in an object that is being serialized. How do I ensure, when the object is deserialized, that result is still correct even if someone maliciously reversed the two? (Suppose the enum is declared elsewhere as a static enum)

I am wondering out of curiosity - I use jar-level authentication to prevent manipulation.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From: http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=50190#265205

> The designers of enum feature decided
>   there is no use case to create new
>   enum objects at runtime. They took
>   great care to not allow it.

Therefore, it looks like enum objects cannot be serialised and deserialised in their entirety. Also, from http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#6469:

> Enum constants are serialized
>   differently than ordinary serializable
>   or externalizable objects. The
>   serialized form of an enum constant
>   consists solely of its name; field
>   values of the constant are not present
>   in the form. To serialize an enum
>   constant, ObjectOutputStream writes
>   the value returned by the enum
>   constant's name method. To deserialize
>   an enum constant, ObjectInputStream
>   reads the constant name from the
>   stream; the deserialized constant is
>   then obtained by calling the
>   java.lang.Enum.valueOf method, passing
>   the constant's enum type along with
>   the received constant name as
>   arguments. Like other serializable or
>   externalizable objects, enum constants
>   can function as the targets of back
>   references appearing subsequently in
>   the serialization stream.
>
> The process by which enum constants
>   are serialized cannot be customized:
>   any class-specific writeObject,
>   readObject, readObjectNoData,
>   writeReplace, and readResolve methods
>   defined by enum types are ignored
>   during serialization and
>   deserialization. Similarly, any
>   serialPersistentFields or
>   serialVersionUID field declarations
>   are also ignored--all enum types have
>   a fixed serialVersionUID of 0L.
>   Documenting serializable fields and
>   data for enum types is unnecessary,
>   since there is no variation in the
>   type of data sent.

Answer (score 5):

Enums are read-replaced during deserialization. Quoting the [serialization release notes](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/serialization/relnotes15.html) for version 1.5:

> The rules for serializing an enum
>   instance differ from those for
>   serializing an "ordinary" serializable
>   object: the serialized form of an enum
>   instance consists only of its enum
>   constant name, along with information
>   identifying its base enum type.
>   Deserialization behavior differs as
>   well--the class information is used to
>   find the appropriate enum class, and
>   the Enum.valueOf method is called with
>   that class and the received constant
>   name in order to obtain the enum
>   constant to return.